# Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.1 versionNameSuffix overriding with flavors dimensions

Tags: android, gradle, dimensions, android-productflavors

I have several flavors with 2 dimensions:

```
    flavorDimensions "buildType", "serverType"

    prod {
        dimension "serverType"
        versionNameSuffix "-prod"
    }

    development {
        dimension "buildType"
    }

    googlePlay {
        dimension "buildType"
        versionNameSuffix "-play"
        versionName "1.1"
    }
```

I want **googlePlay** flavor to override versionNameSuffix of **prod** flavor but it just appends suffixes to the final version name so I have version name like **'1.1-prod-play'** but I want it to be like **'1.1-play'**.

Could someone help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to override versionName like this:

```
    prod {
        dimension "serverType"
        versionName globalConfig.androidVersionName + "-prod"
    }

    development {
        dimension "buildType"
    }

    googlePlay {
        dimension "buildType"
        versionName globalConfig.androidVersionName
    }
```

Where **globalConfig.androidVersionName** is defined by me variable with version name.